# How to loop through multiple level master detail data through linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have three levels of master detail relation, One purchase can contain multiple challan, one challan can contain multiple items. each item has some quantity. I need to calculate total item quantity for every purchase. I've done that by the following, but it takes a lot of time just for a handful of data. I'm worried what will happen when the amount of data becomes large. Is there a way to do this in a single query using join or anything else? Thanks in advance.

```
var allData = (from p in _context.Prq_Purchase.AsEnumerable()
                       //where p.RecordStatus == "NCF"
                       from s in _context.Sys_Supplier
                       where s.SupplierID == p.SupplierID
                       from sa in _context.Sys_SupplierAddress
                       where sa.SupplierAddressID == p.SupplierAddressID
                       orderby p.PurchaseID descending
                       select new PurchaseReceive
                       {
                           PurchaseID = (p.PurchaseID).ToString(),
                           PurchaseNo= p.PurchaseNo,
                           SupplierID = (p.SupplierID).ToString(),
                           SupplierName = s.SupplierName,
                           Address = sa.Address,
                           SupplierAddressID = (p.SupplierAddressID).ToString(),
                           PurchaseCategory = p.PurchaseCategory,
                           PurchaseType = p.PurchaseType,
                           PurchaseYear = p.PurchaseYear,
                           PurchaseDate = (p.PurchaseDate).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"),
                           RecordStatus= DalCommon.ReturnRecordStatus(p.RecordStatus)
                       }).ToList();

        foreach(var Purchase in allData)
        {
            decimal TotalQty = 0;

            var ChallanList= (from c in _context.Prq_PurchaseChallan.AsEnumerable()
                              where (c.PurchaseID).ToString()==Purchase.PurchaseID
                              select c).ToList();



            foreach(var Challan in ChallanList)
            {
                var ItemList = (from i in _context.Prq_PurchaseChallanItem.AsEnumerable()
                                where i.ChallanID == Challan.ChallanID
                                select i).ToList();

                foreach(var Item in ItemList )
                {
                    TotalQty = TotalQty + Item.ReceiveQty;
                }

            }
            Purchase.TotalItem = TotalQty;
        }
```

Comment: Fire up a sql profiler and see what's the query looks like. You might be able to do some optimization there. I think you need use aggregate to do the quantity calculation. Here is a link for your reference. It group by data and then aggregate based on the result. http://www.dev102.com/2008/04/16/how-to-use-aggregate-functions-with-linq-to-sql/

Comment: If `Prq_Purchase` is a database table, then did you intend to perform each query in memory? By calling `AsEnumerable` you are changing the query so that it loads *all* of the records in the table into your program's local memory and then applies the query using LINQ to Objects.

Comment: No, I don't intend that, I used AsEnumerable just to get some methods available like ToString(). I know it sounds kinda wired, but I couldn't apply those methods without using AsEnumerable.

Comment: Do you have navigation properties? purchase.Challans  and Challan.Items? Do you want to get only TotalQuantity and no other values?

Comment: I do have Foreign key relation, so I guess I do have the navigation properties. I want not only the total quantity, but also some other data from the Purchase & Challan table.